# multi thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a loop, but it is too heavy so I would like to share the same in multiple threads, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
while(!labyrinth.exit(bob3) && !labyrinth.exit(bob2)) {

     Collection<Room> accessibleRooms = labyrinth.accessibleRooms(bob3);

     if (bob3.canMove()) {
         destination = bob3.makeChoice(accessibleRooms);
     }

     if (destination != bob3.getPosition()) {
         destination.receive(bob3);
     }

     accessibleRooms = labyrinth.accessibleRooms(bob2);   

     if (bob2.canMove()) {
         destination = bob2.makeChoice(accessibleRooms);
     }

     if (destination != bob2.getPosition()) {
         destination.receive(bob2);
     }
}
```

As you can see, in this loop we have two operations that are identical so is it possible to make each one use a different thread.

Comment: Never seen a post go wiki so fast ;-)

Comment: And yet, the spelling errors remain. This is exactly why there's a reject reason on suggested edits that reads "Too minor".

Comment: Did you search google for sample multithreading code with java? I think that would help you well enough.

Comment: Someone should take care of that French, too :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I personally find that the French part was easier to understand!

Comment: This is because of Winter Bash. Everyone wants to be a clown. :D

Comment: @assylias Being a Frenchman sure helps there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final CyclicBarrier c = new CyclicBarrier(2);

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while ( !labyrinthe.sortir(bob3) )
            {

                Collection<Salle> sallesAccessibles = labyrinthe.sallesAccessibles(bob3);
                if ( bob3.peutSeDeplacer() )
                    destination = bob3.faitSonChoix(sallesAccessibles); // on demande au heros de faire son choix de salle
                if ( destination != bob3.getPosition() )
                    destination.recevoir(bob3); // deplacement
            }
            try
            {
                c.await();
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                ;
            }
            catch ( BrokenBarrierException e )
            {
                ;
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while ( !labyrinthe.sortir(bob2) )
            {
                Collection<Salle> sallesAccessibles = labyrinthe.sallesAccessibles(bob2);
                if ( bob2.peutSeDeplacer() )
                    destination = bob2.faitSonChoix(sallesAccessibles); // on demande au heros de faire son choix de salle
                if ( destination != bob2.getPosition() )
                    destination.recevoir(bob2); // deplacement

            }
            try
            {
                c.await();
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                ;
            }
            catch ( BrokenBarrierException e )
            {
                ;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    c.await();

    System.out.println("Done");
```

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to make "multithreading":

```
while(....){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               // put your code here.
            }
        }
    ).start();
}
```

dont forget to make your variables final

EDIT: you wanted it :)

```
ExecutorService exec= Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
while(....){
    exec.execute(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               // put your code here.
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This will likely result in an unbounded number of threads being created.  If the while loop only runs a few times then why bother threading, if it's going to iterate lots of times you're going to end up with far too many threads.  Much better to use a thread pool and the Executor service for this.

Comment: its the easiest, not the best way :)

Comment: If someone has no idea of threads, `ExecutorService` is far from being easy. this is just a way to start with.

Comment: @kromit I would argue the opposite. The ExecutorService handles the lifecycle and recycling of threads for you.

Comment: There's no accounting for taste.

Comment: thats right. but there is also a difference between "easy to use for me" and "easy for him to understand"